# How to find tooltip text message that is <Strong><br> tag in java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, tooltip, webdriverwait

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("jform_email-lbl"));
Actions mouseOver = new Actions(driver);
mouseOver.moveToElement(element).perform();
//String toolTipText = element.getText();
String toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.id("jform_email-lbl")).getAttribute("title data-original-title");
```

Its giving me `null` value.

HTML:

```
<label id="jform_email-lbl" for="jform_email" class="hasTooltip required" title="" data-original-title="<strong>Email Address</strong><br />Please enter the email address associated with your User account.<br />A verification code will be sent to you. Once you have received the verification code, you will be able to choose a new password for your account."> 
    Email Address
    <span class="star">&nbsp;*</span>
</label>
```

Comment: You could try `getAttribute("data-original-title");`

Answer (score 1):

Try with innerText

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//your locator")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not that much information you provided. You could use `By.TagName("Strong)` and filter them using `By.TagName("br")`. Depending on your DOM you can improve this a lot by just searching in specific `<div>` for instance.

Comment: Please attach this as formatted html code to your initial post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *tooltip* text message you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();
String toolTipElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@class='hasTooltip required' and @id='jform_email-lbl']"))).getAttribute("data-original-title");
```